# CSS webcomponent as footer

Tags: css, web-component

I'm trying to build a generic footer using polymer (webcomponent).

Obviously the footer needs to be attached to the bottom of the page which I can achieve using position fixed with bottom 0px.

The problem with this approach is that when I drop my footer component into a page it doesn't take up any space.

How do I achieve this so that a hosting page doesn't have to know anything about the footer dimensions and still layout correctly.
I.e the footer naturally takes space out of the hosting page as if the footers position was static.

Comment: Please provide some minimal reproducible code

Comment: Please be more specific on *when I drop my footer component into a page it doesn't take up any space*.

Answer (score 1):

Since your footer component will be  `position:static` you will need to have the component add a single `<div>` either just before it or just after it. And then your component can, using JS, derive its own height and assign that height to the new `<div>` that will allow the page to scroll past the footer.

The following code is not a web component but that is irrelevant. It shows that, by adding a final div that is the same height as the footer, you will be able to scroll to see the entire content of the body.

The second copy of the code does not add the extra div and you can't see the final line of text.

```js
document.body.onload = () => {
  const footer = document.querySelector('footer');
  const content = document.querySelector('.content');
  const {height} = footer.getBoundingClientRect();
  const div = document.createElement('div');
  div.style.height = `${height}px`;
  content.append(div);
}
```

```css
footer {
    background: #ddd;
    border-top: 1px solid black;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: 0 -5px;
    padding: 10px;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}

.last {
  border: 1px dashed red;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <p>This is the content of the page. jdlskaj kld jsalkj dlsaj djslak jdjsa djlask jdkasj djasl djasl djaskjd kasjd asjdlk jaskld jaslkjd alksjd askjd lkjflsd fjkhsa fhskjfh dskfhdsjk hfjh dfkjhdas fhdaskj fhdsklajf hkjsahf kjsdahf jksahf kjsdahf afkj hdsakjfh sdkajhf dsakjhfkdjsahfkjdsah fksjalhf sladk</p>
  <p>This is the content of the page. jdlskaj kld jsalkj dlsaj djslak jdjsa djlask jdkasj djasl djasl djaskjd kasjd asjdlk jaskld jaslkjd alksjd askjd lkjflsd fjkhsa fhskjfh dskfhdsjk hfjh dfkjhdas fhdaskj fhdsklajf hkjsahf kjsdahf jksahf kjsdahf afkj hdsakjfh sdkajhf dsakjhfkdjsahfkjdsah fksjalhf sladk</p>
  <p>This is the content of the page. jdlskaj kld jsalkj dlsaj djslak jdjsa djlask jdkasj djasl djasl djaskjd kasjd asjdlk jaskld jaslkjd alksjd askjd lkjflsd fjkhsa fhskjfh dskfhdsjk hfjh dfkjhdas fhdaskj fhdsklajf hkjsahf kjsdahf jksahf kjsdahf afkj hdsakjfh sdkajhf dsakjhfkdjsahfkjdsah fksjalhf sladk</p>
  <p>This is the content of the page. jdlskaj kld jsalkj dlsaj djslak jdjsa djlask jdkasj djasl djasl djaskjd kasjd asjdlk jaskld jaslkjd alksjd askjd lkjflsd fjkhsa fhskjfh dskfhdsjk hfjh dfkjhdas fhdaskj fhdsklajf hkjsahf kjsdahf jksahf kjsdahf afkj hdsakjfh sdkajhf dsakjhfkdjsahfkjdsah fksjalhf sladk</p>
  <p>This is the content of the page. jdlskaj kld jsalkj dlsaj djslak jdjsa djlask jdkasj djasl djasl djaskjd kasjd asjdlk jaskld jaslkjd alksjd askjd lkjflsd fjkhsa fhskjfh dskfhdsjk hfjh dfkjhdas fhdaskj fhdsklajf hkjsahf kjsdahf jksahf kjsdahf afkj hdsakjfh sdkajhf dsakjhfkdjsahfkjdsah fksjalhf sladk</p>
  <p>This is the content of the page. jdlskaj kld jsalkj dlsaj djslak jdjsa djlask jdkasj djasl djasl djaskjd kasjd asjdlk jaskld jaslkjd alksjd askjd lkjflsd fjkhsa fhskjfh dskfhdsjk hfjh dfkjhdas fhdaskj fhdsklajf hkjsahf kjsdahf jksahf kjsdahf afkj hdsakjfh sdkajhf dsakjhfkdjsahfkjdsah fksjalhf sladk</p>
  <p>This is the content of the page. jdlskaj kld jsalkj dlsaj djslak jdjsa djlask jdkasj djasl djasl djaskjd kasjd asjdlk jaskld jaslkjd alksjd askjd lkjflsd fjkhsa fhskjfh dskfhdsjk hfjh dfkjhdas fhdaskj fhdsklajf hkjsahf kjsdahf jksahf kjsdahf afkj hdsakjfh sdkajhf dsakjhfkdjsahfkjdsah fksjalhf sladk</p>
  <p>This is the content of the page. jdlskaj kld jsalkj dlsaj djslak jdjsa djlask jdkasj djasl djasl djaskjd kasjd asjdlk jaskld jaslkjd alksjd askjd lkjflsd fjkhsa fhskjfh dskfhdsjk hfjh dfkjhdas fhdaskj fhdsklajf hkjsahf kjsdahf jksahf kjsdahf afkj hdsakjfh sdkajhf dsakjhfkdjsahfkjdsah fksjalhf sladk</p>
  <p>This is the content of the page. jdlskaj kld jsalkj dlsaj djslak jdjsa djlask jdkasj djasl djasl djaskjd kasjd asjdlk jaskld jaslkjd alksjd askjd lkjflsd fjkhsa fhskjfh dskfhdsjk hfjh dfkjhdas fhdaskj fhdsklajf hkjsahf kjsdahf jksahf kjsdahf afkj hdsakjfh sdkajhf dsakjhfkdjsahfkjdsah fksjalhf sladk</p>
  <p>This is the content of the page. jdlskaj kld jsalkj dlsaj djslak jdjsa djlask jdkasj djasl djasl djaskjd kasjd asjdlk jaskld jaslkjd alksjd askjd lkjflsd fjkhsa fhskjfh dskfhdsjk hfjh dfkjhdas fhdaskj fhdsklajf hkjsahf kjsdahf jksahf kjsdahf afkj hdsakjfh sdkajhf dsakjhfkdjsahfkjdsah fksjalhf sladk</p>
  <p>This is the content of the page. jdlskaj kld jsalkj dlsaj djslak jdjsa djlask jdkasj djasl djasl djaskjd kasjd asjdlk jaskld jaslkjd alksjd askjd lkjflsd fjkhsa fhskjfh dskfhdsjk hfjh dfkjhdas fhdaskj fhdsklajf hkjsahf kjsdahf jksahf kjsdahf afkj hdsakjfh sdkajhf dsakjhfkdjsahfkjdsah fksjalhf sladk</p>
  <p class="last">This is the last line of the body</p>
</div>
<footer>
  This is the footer section
  <div style="text-align: center">Copyright (c) 2019 some company</div>
</footer>
```

This one does not allow you to see the final line:

```css
footer {
    background: #ddd;
    border-top: 1px solid black;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: 0 -5px;
    padding: 10px;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}

.last {
  border: 1px dashed red;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <p>This is the content of the page. jdlskaj kld jsalkj dlsaj djslak jdjsa djlask jdkasj djasl djasl djaskjd kasjd asjdlk jaskld jaslkjd alksjd askjd lkjflsd fjkhsa fhskjfh dskfhdsjk hfjh dfkjhdas fhdaskj fhdsklajf hkjsahf kjsdahf jksahf kjsdahf afkj hdsakjfh sdkajhf dsakjhfkdjsahfkjdsah fksjalhf sladk</p>
  <p>This is the content of the page. jdlskaj kld jsalkj dlsaj djslak jdjsa djlask jdkasj djasl djasl djaskjd kasjd asjdlk jaskld jaslkjd alksjd askjd lkjflsd fjkhsa fhskjfh dskfhdsjk hfjh dfkjhdas fhdaskj fhdsklajf hkjsahf kjsdahf jksahf kjsdahf afkj hdsakjfh sdkajhf dsakjhfkdjsahfkjdsah fksjalhf sladk</p>
  <p>This is the content of the page. jdlskaj kld jsalkj dlsaj djslak jdjsa djlask jdkasj djasl djasl djaskjd kasjd asjdlk jaskld jaslkjd alksjd askjd lkjflsd fjkhsa fhskjfh dskfhdsjk hfjh dfkjhdas fhdaskj fhdsklajf hkjsahf kjsdahf jksahf kjsdahf afkj hdsakjfh sdkajhf dsakjhfkdjsahfkjdsah fksjalhf sladk</p>
  <p>This is the content of the page. jdlskaj kld jsalkj dlsaj djslak jdjsa djlask jdkasj djasl djasl djaskjd kasjd asjdlk jaskld jaslkjd alksjd askjd lkjflsd fjkhsa fhskjfh dskfhdsjk hfjh dfkjhdas fhdaskj fhdsklajf hkjsahf kjsdahf jksahf kjsdahf afkj hdsakjfh sdkajhf dsakjhfkdjsahfkjdsah fksjalhf sladk</p>
  <p>This is the content of the page. jdlskaj kld jsalkj dlsaj djslak jdjsa djlask jdkasj djasl djasl djaskjd kasjd asjdlk jaskld jaslkjd alksjd askjd lkjflsd fjkhsa fhskjfh dskfhdsjk hfjh dfkjhdas fhdaskj fhdsklajf hkjsahf kjsdahf jksahf kjsdahf afkj hdsakjfh sdkajhf dsakjhfkdjsahfkjdsah fksjalhf sladk</p>
  <p>This is the content of the page. jdlskaj kld jsalkj dlsaj djslak jdjsa djlask jdkasj djasl djasl djaskjd kasjd asjdlk jaskld jaslkjd alksjd askjd lkjflsd fjkhsa fhskjfh dskfhdsjk hfjh dfkjhdas fhdaskj fhdsklajf hkjsahf kjsdahf jksahf kjsdahf afkj hdsakjfh sdkajhf dsakjhfkdjsahfkjdsah fksjalhf sladk</p>
  <p>This is the content of the page. jdlskaj kld jsalkj dlsaj djslak jdjsa djlask jdkasj djasl djasl djaskjd kasjd asjdlk jaskld jaslkjd alksjd askjd lkjflsd fjkhsa fhskjfh dskfhdsjk hfjh dfkjhdas fhdaskj fhdsklajf hkjsahf kjsdahf jksahf kjsdahf afkj hdsakjfh sdkajhf dsakjhfkdjsahfkjdsah fksjalhf sladk</p>
  <p>This is the content of the page. jdlskaj kld jsalkj dlsaj djslak jdjsa djlask jdkasj djasl djasl djaskjd kasjd asjdlk jaskld jaslkjd alksjd askjd lkjflsd fjkhsa fhskjfh dskfhdsjk hfjh dfkjhdas fhdaskj fhdsklajf hkjsahf kjsdahf jksahf kjsdahf afkj hdsakjfh sdkajhf dsakjhfkdjsahfkjdsah fksjalhf sladk</p>
  <p>This is the content of the page. jdlskaj kld jsalkj dlsaj djslak jdjsa djlask jdkasj djasl djasl djaskjd kasjd asjdlk jaskld jaslkjd alksjd askjd lkjflsd fjkhsa fhskjfh dskfhdsjk hfjh dfkjhdas fhdaskj fhdsklajf hkjsahf kjsdahf jksahf kjsdahf afkj hdsakjfh sdkajhf dsakjhfkdjsahfkjdsah fksjalhf sladk</p>
  <p>This is the content of the page. jdlskaj kld jsalkj dlsaj djslak jdjsa djlask jdkasj djasl djasl djaskjd kasjd asjdlk jaskld jaslkjd alksjd askjd lkjflsd fjkhsa fhskjfh dskfhdsjk hfjh dfkjhdas fhdaskj fhdsklajf hkjsahf kjsdahf jksahf kjsdahf afkj hdsakjfh sdkajhf dsakjhfkdjsahfkjdsah fksjalhf sladk</p>
  <p>This is the content of the page. jdlskaj kld jsalkj dlsaj djslak jdjsa djlask jdkasj djasl djasl djaskjd kasjd asjdlk jaskld jaslkjd alksjd askjd lkjflsd fjkhsa fhskjfh dskfhdsjk hfjh dfkjhdas fhdaskj fhdsklajf hkjsahf kjsdahf jksahf kjsdahf afkj hdsakjfh sdkajhf dsakjhfkdjsahfkjdsah fksjalhf sladk</p>
  <p class="last">This is the last line of the body</p>
</div>
<footer>
  This is the footer section
  <div style="text-align: center">Copyright (c) 2019 some company</div>
</footer>
```